# Problem to pass JSON / Ajax to PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm capturing the JSON / Ajax response in an id of a span, all right. But I can not save the response in a PHP variable.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#enviar").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var nombre = $("#nombre").val(),
 apellido = $("#apellido").val(),
 edad = $("#edad").val(),

 datos = {"nombre":nombre, "apellido":apellido,"edad":edad};

 $.ajax({
  url: "procesa.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: datos
 }).done(function(respuesta){
  if (respuesta.estado === "ok") {
    $('#myName').text(respuesta.nombre);
             $('#myApellido').text(respuesta.apellido);
             $('#myEdad').text(respuesta.edad);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" accept="text/plain"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" accept="text/plain"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="edad" placeholder="Edad" accept="text/plain">

<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

The answer is printed well in the id of the span, but in all the POST options that I tried, nothing is printed.

```html
<p>Name: <span id="myName"></span></p>
<p>Apellido: <span id="myApellido"></span></p>
<p>Edad: <span id="myEdad"></span></p>
<?php
echo $_POST["nombre"]; //Key json, nothing is printed.
echo $_POST["myName"]; //Name of var response, nothing is printed.
echo $_POST["respuesta.nombre"]; //Anothe json, nothing is printed.
$character = json_decode($respuesta);
echo $character->nombre; //nothing is printed. desperation
?>
```

The procesa.php

```html
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//Guardamos los datos en un array
$datos = array(
'estado' => 'ok',
'nombre' => $nombre, 
'apellido' => $apellido, 
'edad' => $edad
);
//Devolvemos el array pasado a JSON como objeto
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `var_dump()` your `$_REQUEST` to see where your data is

Comment: You are sending the `datos` object to the PHP server so only those keys would be available. `$_POST["myName"]` does not exist but `$_POST["apellido"]` should exist. If `$_POST["apellido"]` has no data then that means your JS did not give it any data.

Comment: You are placing the data in a span. Spans do not get sent to the PHP when you submit a form as thay are not input fields

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that JSON_FORCE_OBJECT is not available until php 5.3; if you are running an older version it will return null. That said, there's no reason to include that with the object you are using. It will return an object since you are using key/value array.

Comment: The html/php with spans... what is that exactly? Is that part of the same page the form is in? Unless you POST to that page, php won't have access to those values.

Comment: var_dump($data); NULL for WillardSolutions
What matters is the response arrangement. This extracts the key 'name', 'apellido' and 'edad'. What is shown in the span. For MonkeyZeus.
PHP Version 5.6 For Lawrence Johnson

Comment: So, based on your two downvoted answers plus lack of explanation, I can only guess that what you're trying to do is just fundamentally flawed logic. Your `$respuesta` variable is only available in the AJAX handler `procesa.php`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, nobody gives a correct answer. If someone asks a question, it is because they do not know the answer and it is supposed that here they can receive help, only very few are concerned to understand the question and try to provide some solution, but there are others who think they are wise / genius of the codes, they only criticize, they do not contribute anything.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple really.

In your Javascript you have this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "procesa.php", <-- data is sent to this page
    type: "POST",
    ...
});
```

Then for that page you have this:

```
The procesa.php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
//Guardamos los datos en un array
$datos = array(
    'estado' => 'ok',
    'nombre' => $nombre, <-- this is undefined
    'apellido' => $apellido, <-- this is undefined
    'edad' => $edad <-- this is undefined
);
//Devolvemos el array pasado a JSON como objeto
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Whatever this is:

```
<p>Name: <span id="myName"></span></p>
<p>Apellido: <span id="myApellido"></span></p>
<p>Edad: <span id="myEdad"></span></p>
<?php
    echo $_POST["nombre"]; //Key json, nothing is printed.
    echo $_POST["myName"]; //Name of var response, nothing is printed.
    echo $_POST["respuesta.nombre"]; //Anothe json, nothing is printed.
    $character = json_decode($respuesta);
    echo $character->nombre; //nothing is printed. desperation
?>
```

It's clearly not part of `procesa.php` which is were you send your AJAX post.  Therefore, what should be obvious is that you cannot get your post data from that location, because that is not where you sent it.  The place you send it doesn't have any code to handle it and hence the issue.

Well at least based on the code that was posted.

Comment: I kind of took a guess, too, but I think he may have been trying to create a no javascript fallback to his form.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson - that was why I didn't offer an actual solution, only a take on what looks to be wrong.  It's hard to say without more to go on.

Comment: I did not put the complete code of procesa.php, because I thought you understood it. Also, it is not the problem posed.
But here I make it complete.

Comment: $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellido"];
$edad = $_POST["edad"];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$datos = array(
'estado' => 'ok',
'nombre' => $nombre, 
'apellido' => $apellido, 
'edad' => $edad);
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);